Downstream Electron subtitles download
I'm trying to download manifest content within Electron. I'm using the following package: https://github.com/castlabs/downstream_electron
I'm having problems downloading the subtitles. Although the audio files and video segments are being downloaded successfully, I'm having a problem with the subtitle files.
Although in the local directory the subtitle files are being downloaded, the download gives an error, and in the download progress the subtitles are at 0% progress.
My manifest is in DASH format and is generated by a vodpackager (https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module). The subtitle files are in .vtt format.
In my manifest, the subtitles are defined with the following syntax:
<AdaptationSet
        id="3"
        contentType="text"
        lang="ro">
      <Representation
          id="3"
          bandwidth="0"
          mimeType="text/vtt"
          subsegmentAlignment="true">
        <BaseURL>dash/sub-f5.vtt</BaseURL>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>

I think the error may be in my manifest since with a test stream the download returns a status of FINISHED instead of ERROR.
I've compared both manifests and there doesn't seem to be any mismatch between the syntax.
Thanks in advance for your help!
